# How to Iterate through ResultSet

Tags: resultset, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My SELECT_QUERY_RETURNS_LIST returns 5 results, But following while loop prints only 4.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_QUERY_RETURNS_LIST, new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        int count = 1;
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String payload = resultSet.getString(1);
            LOGGER.info("My result {}...",count++);
        }
    }
});
```

Logically It is correct as [spring jdbc RowCallbackHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) tells

> rs - the ResultSet to process (pre-initialized for the current row)

In firstline Itself we told resultSet.next(), So It starts from second record which results in printing 4 records. And following code works as my expcectation

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_QUERY_RETURNS_LIST, new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        int count = 1;
        String payload = resultSet.getString(1);
        LOGGER.info("My result {}...",count++);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            payload = resultSet.getString(1);
            LOGGER.info("My result {}...",count++);
        }
    }
});
```

So please tell solution to minimize code before while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by using do while instead of while loop

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_QUERY_RETURNS_LIST, new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        int count = 1;
        do {
            payload = resultSet.getString(1);
            LOGGER.info("My result {}...",count++);
        } while (resultSet.next());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a loop with `RowCallbackHandler` interface. It is used inside `JdbcTemplate.RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor` and there is already a `while` loop over `ResultSet` entries.
The only problem is that there is no index in `RowCallbackHandler.processRow` signature, so you have to rely on an external counter, I suppose.